# "Go over for" meaning "go for"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, spoken-english

A line from the movie *Killers* grates.

> You just pulled a robot voice. All right, don't worry. There's a certain segment of the population that **goes over big for** that sort of thing. ([for more context check out YouTube](https://youtu.be/okBtpNRlKuo?t=19))

To say "something goes over well" is to say "something is being received well". The line at issue seems to be a misuse of this phrase and should be "goes for" in stead of "goes over for". But could this be a regional thing? Does anybody use "go over" the same way as this quoted line in the movie?

Comment: It's a fairly common American expression: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-over#go-over__14

I often hear it with performing arts and things like professional wrestling.

Comment: @kaipmdh but that is how it is supposed to be used, as I mentioned. The quoted line uses the phrase the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific expression "go over big for" is not that uncommon, but also, I think, a bit of a special case.  It is, in my opinion, sort of a cross between "to
go for" (to be interested in) and "to go over big" (to be enthusiastically received), so it essentially means "to become enthusiastically interested in *(something)* when it is presented to *(some group of people)*".

In this sense, it is somewhat similar to "to fall for", but without any of the romantic implications that that phrase often has (more about enthusiasm than romance).

It should be noted that it really only works if the word "big" is included in there, so this isn't a meaning that's true of "to go over" in general.  Essentially, "to go over big (for)" is its own compound verb here, with a special meaning.  I also tend to feel it really only works when talking about groups of people, or possibly individuals in an audience setting, as it does still have an inherent implication of somebody giving some sort of presentation, and describing the reaction of those receiving it.

Comment: Great answer. I agree this particular case seems to be a cross. I still have an issue with "someone goes over big for something." _The toy goes over big with kids._ is correct. Not _My niece goes over big with/for the toy._ The subject and object of the phrasal verb seem to be inverted in the usage in question. "Go over big for" appears to be a rare and hardly attested usage according to [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+over+big+for%22) Only a handful hits